# VSCode gives me random words suggestion as I type

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is what it shows and it doesn't give me relevant suggestions.

[image]

Comment: You are not getting "random words".  You are getting something that is base64 encoded.  But we can't tell much from the screenshot that you posted.  If you want an answer you are going to have to invest more effort in writing a decent question.  Please 1) take the [Site Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), 2) read ["How to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 3) ["Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551).   Then EDIT your question to improve it based on what you learned.

Answer (score 0):

They might not be random words after all. They might be words or in this case, addresses of the previous srcs of img tag.